# Workbook-2 macro calls Workbook-1 macro fails with error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, macros, call

To demonstrate that it can work, I want to have a macro (tried both Sub and Function) in one workbook (test1.xlsm) that does a simple MsgBox and a macro in a second workbook (test2.xlsm) that calls the first macro (using Application.Run "test1.xlsm!macro1)". I have tried putting the macro for both workbooks in ThisWorkbook and in the worksheet View-Code and in the General Alt-F11 Module space. The workbook being called starts out either opened or closed. Regardless, I get error 1004 (macro unavailable or disabled). Numerous web searches proved non-helpful.

Comment: Best to show the exact code you used.

Comment: Did you try Google first?

Comment: Inexplicably, when I tried my example on another PC it worked as expected.  --

Answer (score 0):

```
   Application.Run "'test1.xlsm'!macro1"
```